# Limit on calling CreateProcess from a service

Tags: visual-c++, service, createprocess

I have a program written in Visual C++ that is compiled with Visual Studio 2005, running on Windows 2003.

Within the program, it repeatly calls CreateProcess to launch a program that just repeatly sleep and display a message to the screen, with the following parameters:

```
CreateProcess(app_pathname, (char*) full_app_name.chars(), 
                       NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 0, 0, &si, &pi)
```

and supplied si has:

```
memset( &si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWDEFAULT;
    si.lpTitle = (char*) cmdLine;
```

What I observed is that if I run this program from a service, no new process are launched beyond 124, and no errors are returned from CreateProcess() API call.

However, if the program was ran from visual studio or command line, then I don't have this limit.

I tried to change the "LogOn" tab to use the same user account that I am running from the command line, as well changed the "Allow service to ineract with desktop" but did not see any difference in behaviour.   From looking at the CreateProcess API as well doing research on the internet, I wasn't able to find the answer to this.   Is there any limitation on the number of process spawned by a service?

Comment: Maybe there is leak of some vital system resources, preventing new processes from running. Do you close process/thread handles after each `CreateProcess()`? Try to use some tools to detect leaks, e.g. HandleEx or just TaskManager.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but not from a service. The app I'm launching is using MFC (via the shared MFC DLL) and I get to around 125 and it fails.  I'm going to refactor my code to limit the number of processes using a special thread/queue but I'm still keen to know what limit I'm hitting.